# What does the "new " keyword in .net actually do?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, allocation

I know that the `new` keyword is calling the class constructor but at which stage do we allocate memory for the class?

In my understanding it should correspond to the `GCHandle.Alloc(Object)` method but I'm unable to find the connection.

Comment: _"But at which stage we allocte memory for the class?"_ - you don't; the runtime does.  What are you trying to do and why you want to know this?

Comment: Actually this is only a theoretickal question. I just whant to understand how .net is working with memory.

Comment: Well all memory management is done by the CLR, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx). If you want to know the basics of how .NET handles memory (de)allocation, take a look at the [garbage collector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx) pages. If you want to learn how memory management in general works, you can start at [Memory Allocation (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk1k7x6x.aspx).

Comment: I recommend to use the book: "CLR via C#" for strong .net fundamentals.  All these concepts are explained so well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The *new* operator is implemented in the CLR.  It allocates memory from the garbage collected heap and executes the class constructor.

GCHandle.Alloc() is *not* the same.  That takes advantage of a separate mechanism in the GC to create references to objects, references that are stored in a separate table and scanned in addition to object references found normally during a garbage collection.  You must pass Alloc() an existing object reference, it adds another.  Useful to create weak and pinning references and a mechanism to allow unmanaged code to store a reference to a managed object and keep it alive.  The [gcroot<> template class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f.aspx) in C++/CLI takes advantage of it.

Answer (score 10):

Everything for object creation is hidden behind the `newobj` opcode (or `initobj` for value-types). As such, it is **entirely an implementation detail** how and where memory is allocated, and how that ties into other memory management structures.